# Adding media queries to grails resources plugin

Tags: css, grails

I'm using the grails resources plugin for my CSS and would like to know if there is a way to add media queries to the resource.

So I'd like to take the media query from the below source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:500px)" href="/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

And add it into the resource format:
resource url: '/css/stylesheet.css'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in [the resource DSL](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/single.html#3.1%20The%20resource%20DSL) with `attrs` property, like:

```
modules = {
    core {
        dependsOn 'jquery, utils'
        defaultBundle 'ui'
        resource url:'/css/print.css', attrs:[media:'print']
        .....
    }
}
```